# wix-react-native-navigation v2 statusBar not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

I am trying `react-native-navigation V2` but not able to change the status bar color.

```
Navigation.setDefaultOptions({
 statusBar: {
 visible: true,
 style: "dark",
 backgroundColor: "red"
},
topBar: {
 background: {
  color: COLOR.primaryColor
 },
 title: {
  text: "ExampleWix",
  fontSize: 22,
  color: "white"
 },
 visible: true
}
});
```

But this is working only on the action bar and nothing happening to the status bar and it remains white. I am using RN v= 0.54.2 and react-native-navigation = 2.0.2373

**UPDATE**

Update your `RNN` and you will be able to change `status bar` color

Comment: Did you find any solution changing the status bar color and style?

Comment: @ChristosLytras I am using `    "react-native-navigation": "^2.0.2427",
` this version now and it's working fine

Comment: Yes you're right. I'm using `2.0.2478` and it works just fine. I just had the `statusBar` option at a wrong hierachy spot.

Comment: @ChristosLytras Cool

Answer (score 13):

A bit late, but for the people that came here from Google:

If you're using iOS. Be sure to set the `View controller-based status bar appearance` or `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` in the Info.plist to `YES`.

Comment: This fixed it for me!

Comment: This solved my issue, now I just need to figure out how to change the background colour and we're golden :)

Comment: You save my day!